# Unable to resize window running TestCafe on Chrome headless

Tags: google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, google-chrome-headless

I'm having an error when trying to use .resizeWindow on my tests, but it's only failing when I run my tests against headless mode. The error stated as Warning is the following:

```
    Warnings (1):
 --
  Was unable to resize the window due to an error.

  Cannot read property 'Emulation' of undefined
```

I'm running my tests in:

```
 - HeadlessChrome 70.0.3538 / Mac OS X 10.13.6
 Testcafe version 0.20.4
```

The resizeWindow instruction is set within my beforeEach as follows:

```
 .beforeEach(async t => {
      await t.navigateTo(`${testDomain}${Var.url_listing_general}`)
        .resizeWindow(1420, 750);
    }
  });
```

Comment: It's headless. Why would you need to resize a headless browser?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. I've prepared a screencast https://drive.google.com/file/d/17YQst5vm_74-COd--3pfTo41tNesSEJz/view?usp=sharing . Can you update to the latest testcafe version? If it does not help, provide us with a sample project demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @lloyd I had the same idea as you, that it doesn't matter that I'm running my tests on headless mode, however since we have different layout based on the window size, some elements will not be present if the window size does not allow it. That's why I came to the need of resize the window even if we are in headless, actually I read in some place that by default, the headless window size is of 800x600. If this is true, my expected elements will not be found by testcafe.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKamev I'll try using the last version as you did, If that works, there is a Bug on the Testcafe Version 0.20.

Comment: @Alextgda, have you had a chance to check out the latest TestCafe version to see how it works? If there's a bug in version 0.20, the best way to address it is to upgrade to the latest TestCafe version ([0.23.0](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/blog/testcafe-v0-23-0-released.html)) where it might be fixed.

Comment: @AlexSkorkin I tried again using the TestCafe version 0.23.0, and I had the same result. I'm still unable to make it work. The only way I found was to resize the window from the Chrome options like the following example: `testcafe 'chrome:headless --window-size="1420,740" test.js'`

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to do resize not in `beforeEach` part, but in a test as first line?

Also, maybe it's foolish and not important, but in you code sample you have extra `}` at the end `beforeEach` section, can it be cause of a problem?